# Cucumber plants drying out?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

My cucumber plants have been drying out and the leaves are turning brown and white and I’m not sure what the problem is. I planted them about a month ago and there weren’t any issues. I’ve tried increasing the water and decreasing the water with no luck. It doesn’t seem like there any pests and they get about 6 hours a sun a day.

Any suggestions???!!

Thank you!

[image]